# Can my PS5 still access the Playstation store with old Firmware

Tags: psn, ps5

I got a PS5 several months ago direct from Sony.  Truth is I've only used it a couple times, and I don't play games with friends and don't like to update my operating systems unless there is a real compelling reason for me to do so.  I just decided to check out its media player and found that I can't because I'm not on the latest firmware.  I'm certain that on my PS4, I could still access the store, media features, etc. even on an older firmware I just couldn't play games online.

Does PS5 really not let you do ANYTHING other than play local games, without being on the latest firmware?

Comment: I don't have a PS5 yet, but I'm guessing the reason you need to update your PS5 to access the media player is because the media player might not be installed by default and needs to be downloaded from the PSN Store first. By the way, I'm pretty sure the PS4 doesn't allow you access to the store if you're not up-to-date.

Comment: Interesting.  PS4 does allow accessing the store even if not on the latest firmware as I've done it many times.  Of course can't play anything I buy with anyone unless I update, but I can browse the store.  Also locks out access to certain other features but I forget which... I think voice chat is one.

Comment: BTW @Nolonar it appears your comment is in fact the answer (that it wasn't installed by default and I needed to have downloaded it while on current firmware).  If you'd care to make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I also had blocked access to PSStore with outdated firmware of my console. When I wanted to enter the store I got dialog with notice that it's necessary to update the firmware. I don't have PS5, but I'm pretty sure that nothing changed in this case.

Comment: Interesting, maybe Sony changed that at some point... I haven't used my PS4 in quite some time but I know I used to be able to go to the store even on old firmware, because I would always download the latest PSN games, I just couldn't play them online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the PS4 and PS5 disable PlayStation Store and PlayStation Network access when a firmware update is made available that is mandatory. This is usually the case when a major update is release.

With minor updates (e.g v9.0.1 to v9.0.2), these are usually optional, unless a specific game requires it. There are some exceptions, like if the update is security related, e.g. to prevent jailbreaking.

If updating the firmware is an issue, leaving the console on stand by ("Rest mode") will auto update the console as and when new firmware updates are released. I've had the PS5 for over an year and the updates haven't really bothered me as the console is better at updating itself than the PS4.

Comment: OK it must be the "small updates are optional" issue then that has allowed me to access the store on my PS4 so many times, even though I wasn't updated.  And I disable automatic updates so the console will never update without me being fully aware of it.